# How do I solve this data structure

Tags: recursion, data-structures

I need help with this data structure question.
each tree has this properties:
right
left
color
key

here are the details:
picture of example tree
https://i.gyazo.com/85a59c69301c214ddc03f2d54324ca6f.png

A good path is a path where parent and child don't have the same colors (for example good path is red-white-red-white or white-red-white-red)

you need to find the longest good path inside a given tree and print its length. (in this example tree output would be 5)

for example in this tree the longest path is
17->13->32->18->22

rules:
you can have other functions to assist you.
you may use fixed number of variables like x,y,z.
you cannot use additional data structures.

not even sure if its recursion or not.

Comment: this is a question from a test. that I am studying for.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: imagine if the node of 18 was red

in this case

18 would get 3 from his left side
and right is a leaf that returns 1

so if 18 decides to return 5 (left+1+right)

how would the root of the tree (20) would know that 18 chose to disconnect from the tree by going right?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Note that this is more of a graph problem than a tree problem.  It appears that you do not have a *parent* field in the node structure, correct?

Answer (score 0):

To get you moving, let's look at the basic properties that can affect a legal tree:

- leaf node (dead end; return length of 1)
- both children have same color as parent (dead end at parent node, return 0)
- one child has color different from parent (follow the one different branch, return that depth + 1)
- both children have color different from parent (follow both, return left + 1 + right)

That should get you to form detailed pseudo-code for a solution.